# SharePoint 2013 - Calendar view - Show 3 lines of information

Tags: calendar, sharepoint-calendar

How can I show 3 lines of information - Title, Location & Category in Calendar view? I have already hide the Start time & End time, but it is still showing in the calendar view and that is t[image]oo only 2 lines of information.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a calculated column which concatenates the Title, Location, and Category columns. Use the below formula in your calculated column.

> =[Title]&" - "&[Location]&" - "&[Category]

Then, modify your calendar view and change the "Month View Title" column to your new calculated column.

The monthly calendar events will now show the values for Title, Location, and Category in this format: "Title - Location - Category".

Comment: Fantastic, thank You much!

Answer (score 2):

I can't understand exactly what you want to do. But if you want 3 lines of information in for a calendar placed in a web part, you can follow these steps:-

1. Go to your Calendar List and select Calendar.
2. Then from the drop down for current view select current events.
3. Now click on the List and click on modify this view.
4. Now uncheck all the meta-datas(columns) you don't want show in the web part.
5. Now add a new web part 'Calendar' and edit the web part properties.
6. Then select the 'selected view' as current events.

Note:- You can also use your own custom view for the Calendar web part.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @Mohd. I would like to do the same in 'Calendar View', not any other view. I would like to show 3 - 'Title, Location & Category' - details for any events in calendar view.